# php with retrieving data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, function, dreamweaver

i am creating a search process that i want to retrieve the data in the MySQL database and display it in a droplist  each table contain 2 fields one is id and other is name

the code or the function of the country work very well but the other function of the specialization do not display anything. if anyone can help plz

## function.php

```
<?php
 require_once('db.inc.php'); 

function connect(){
   mysql_connect(DB_Host, DB_User ,DB_Pass )or die("could not connect to the database" .mysql_error());

   mysql_select_db(DB_Name)or die("could not select database");

}
  function close(){

  mysql_close();

  }

  function countryQuery(){

  $countryData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country");

  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($countryData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $record['country_name'] .  '">' . $record['country_name'] . '</option>';

  }

}

function specializtionQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization'] . '</option>';

  }


}
?>
```

## index.php

```
<?php
  require_once('func.inc.php'); 
  connect(); 


?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>testDroplistdown</title>
</head>

<body>
<p align="center">
<select name="dropdown">
  <?php countryQuery(); ?>
</select>
  <?php close(); ?>
</p>
<p align="left">
<select name="dropdown2">
  <?php specializationQuery(); ?>
</select>
  <?php close(); ?>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the function name in the definition:

```
function specializtionQuery(){
```

...then you're calling:

```
<?php specializationQuery(); ?>
```

Note the missing `a` in the function name.

Comment: thanks for the answer but still not getting any data to be displayed